# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Super User's [fourth moderator election](https://superuser.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: DavidPostill]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://superuser.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learns the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking [Oliver Salzburg](https://superuser.com/users/36744/oliver-salzburg) for his years of service. He was elected way back in [July, 2012](https://superuser.com/election/2) and is stepping down as a diamond moderator today.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://superuser.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.com/results/6642873269223424/0).

Comment: Congratulations David and good luck! Also, that must be the shortest election summary report *ever*.

Comment: First action as mod: Correct a CM's grammar. Yup, this one'll do just fine.

Comment: My vote well spent. Good luck!

Comment: Congrats @David! A well deserved win. And thanks Oliver - for your service to the site we are greatful. Finally, nice work to all of the other candidates who nominated - just because you aren't a mod (yet?) doesn't mean that your other contributions to the site are worthless, we appreciate them fully. Just being willing to nominate yourself for the role is fantastic.

Comment: I demand a recount! I voted for La La Land!

Comment: Congratulations David :D

Comment: @DavidPostill [For he's a jolly good fellow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYLtBFQDAGE) I wouldn't have expected anything else...So predicable... LOL... Congrats!!

Comment: Congrats David you deserve it and thank you Oliver

Comment: Congratulations uncle David! :D

Answer (score 37):

First, farewell to Oliver Salzburg. Thank you for all your service. All the current moderators deserve congratulations as well -- the fact that we didn't need an election for three years shows your effectiveness and steadfastness. Well done!

And now: congratulations, DavidPostill! Your dedication to this site is clear and I am 100% sure you will be a highly effective moderator. I can't claim to be surprised at your winning -- indeed, I think we all saw this coming weeks ago. It was an honor to be in the same race. Welcome aboard, and I will see you in TL!

Comment: Thank you and, welcome @DavidPostill :)

Comment: +1, I saw it coming weeks ago